# Store image thumbnails on server with Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I'm using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) with Angular.js to upload images, but i didn't find a method, how can i upload thumbnails to my server.

```
.dropzone({
      url: "/gallery/add",
      maxFilesize: 100,
      paramName: "uploadfile",
      createImageThumbnails: true,
      thumbnailWidth: 200,
      init: function() {

        this.on('addedfile', function(file) {

           // maybe something here

        });

        this.on('thumbnail', function(file){

         // or here

        });
      }
    });
```

Problem only with thumbnails

Comment: Its not dropzone.js but it also has ability to upload file and somehow, in demo page, show thumbnail :) https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/

Answer (score 6):

At present, this is not possible with Dropzone.js. There was a [Github Issue](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/89) a while back that requested this functionality. You can review the comments but I tend to agree with what the first commenter says

1. for large images creating thumbnails clientside is slow (the browsers is not a good image processing tool), that is also why thumbnails are only generated for images < 2MB
2. doing this on the server is easy, cheap and more versatile.